# How I can disable daemons / services (that run and that I can't kill) in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, process, daemon, kill

I want to kill a process on MacOS but after `kill -9 PID` it starts immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out id this process is a daemon/service:
`sudo launchctl list | grep PROCESS_NAME`

If so (most probably), there are some places where you can find related .plist daemon files:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/ - Per-user agents provided by the user.
/Library/LaunchAgents/ - Per-user agents provided by the root.
/Library/LaunchDaemons/ - System-wide daemons provided by the root.
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ - System-wide daemons provided by MacOS
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/ - Per-user agents provided by MacOS.
```

After you find the related file:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /path/to/DAEMON_NAME.plist
```

And now you can remove this file.

Comment: 1) You only need to 'sudo' on the system processes, not the user ones. 2) In MacOS you first need to boot into recovery mode to disable SIP 3) People generally do `(sudo) launchctl unload -wF ...`, use the -F flag too 4) Very bad idea to delete the .plist entirely, you might be breaking something necessary or that you want to reenable in future. Or at absolute minimum, it's useful to preserve the ability to know which software launches which processes. Much better practice is to then hide the .plist, typically by renaming it: (sudo) mv -f ... .plist.bak